# Determining if a remote subscriber is temporarily disconnected

Tags: opentok, tokbox

This is in the context of reconnection. As a moderator I want to know when a remote subscriber (a client subscriber of the stream that I publish) drops temporarily its connection.

First, the subscriber events disconnect, reconnecting and reconnected are dispatched locally on the remote side, that is the guy that loses its connection. The publisher receives no events about the remote connection that gets lost.

Second, I tried to use the 'signal' JS web jdk as well as the server jdk. The idea was to get an error when sending a signal to a 'temporarily' disconnected client, but all I got is successful responses for both, the server I get 204 status code. So I understand the signals are queue and sent when the remote client gets reconnected.

So far I found no way to determine from a connected client when another client loses its connection 'temporarily entering in the 'reconnecting' state.

The signal API only sends error when the client gets completely disconnected from the session, not temporarily disconnected.

I know can mimic this with signals and timeouts, but this way I need the server to trust my client and I really need to validate this on the server side as well, otherwise it would be 'hackable'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

When any client loses connection, a `connectionDestroyed` event is dispatched to all clients including the client that lost the connection. There is also a [`Connection Event`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/ConnectionEvent.html) object which includes a `reason` and a [`Connection`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Connection.html) property that is dispatched with the event.

The reason for the connection destroyed event varies depending on if the client called the `disconnect` method on the [`Session`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Session.html) object, was force disconnected, or disconnected due to a network condition. In the context of a client temporarily losing connection, the `connectionDestroyed` event will fire with the `reason` property of the event data set to `networkDisconnected`.

As for the `signal` queue, by default, any signals you send while the client is temporarily disconnected from a session are queued and sent when (and if) it successfully reconnects. You can set the `retryAfterReconnect` property to `false` in the `options` you pass into the `Session.signal()` method to prevent signals from being queued while the client is disconnected.

For more information on Automatic Reconnection, please visit: https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/connect-session/js/#automatic_reconnection

Comment: Ok, but still as long as the client is "temporarily" disconnected I have no way to detect that. "connectionDestroyed" is dispatched when the clients get disconnected from the stream (reconnection fails). And the signal API sends 204 (success) even if I send signals to a temporarily disconnected client with retryAfterReconnect set to false.

Comment: The connectionDestroyed event will fire even if they temporarily get disconnected because it's disconnecting from the session (albeit temporarily). As for the signal API, you're seeing the 204 even when no one is in the session?

As for the retry after reconnect, you cannot set the retryAfterReconnect to false on the server side. That API is only for the client side part of the application and only affects client that is in process of reconnecting.

Comment: @Manik how long this auto-reconnection will retry until it will throw the Disconnection even?