# OpenTok, detect if remote subscriber has poor connection or temporarily disconnected or network disconnected for Android and iOS SDK

Tags: opentok, tokbox

We are not able to detect subscribers'/clients' disconnected signal or poor network connection with Android/iOS SDK, however, we are able to detect with OpenTok web (JS).
The below link suggested for the web which is working fine our end too, but we need the same for OpenTok Android and iOS SDK.
[Determining if a remote subscriber is temporarily disconnected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52339216/determining-if-a-remote-subscriber-is-temporarily-disconnected).

we need sample code to detect poor connection or network disconnected at subscribers end for both Android and iOS. if anybody faced a similar problem and has a workaround then please suggest.

our aim to show messages on the mobile phone if subscribers have poor connection issues or trying to reconnect.

Comment: Hi, did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are analogous re-connection callbacks for Android and iOS as well. Reconnection callbacks get triggered when a client tries to automatically reconnect after losing its connection to an OpenTok session. Otherwise, if a client cannot reconnect, the SessionListener's "disconnected" method gets triggered.

To verify if session reconnect APIs are working fine at your end, we recommend you to implement the necessary callbacks and manually check if the registered callbacks gets triggered or not by disconnecting network and then reconnecting it again.
Please checkout the below link for implementing callback APIs:

**Android**:
https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/reference/com/opentok/android/Session.ReconnectionListener.html

**iOS**: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Protocols/OTSessionDelegate.html#//api/name/sessionDidBeginReconnecting

Hope it helps!